# Which namespaces can I use for writing xamarin packages compatible with all implementations?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create some nuget package that contains API compatible with all Xamarin implementations (UWP, iOS, Android), in order to use it across all devices that can run Xamarin apps.

I heard that the `System.*`  namespaces are the ones compatible with them all, but is there any other namespace that is universal? And I think that the `Windows.*` namespace is the one compatible only with UWP, right?

Would like to have a detailed explanation of this topic.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/

Comment: There are no C# Namespaces. Only .NET ones. UWP is also not a Operating System, but a way way to write Apps (wich are hopefully OS agnostic). I call their kind a "GUI technology". As long as you programm targets .NET Core it should be OS agnostic.

Comment: @Christopher UWP is not an OS, but it is a platform, and I'm not sure its going to go beyond Windows.  XF can target other platforms besides Windows though.

Comment: @Andy: UWP is the primary GUI technology for .NET Core. And .NET core definitely has official ports for other OS. It is a bit unclear how much it is actually realized.

Comment: @Christopher Do you have a link to that?  Because UWP is short for Universal *Windows* Platform.  Maybe something's changed; I know .Net Core is multi-platform, but I was pretty sure UWP is Windows OS only.

Comment: UWP is *Windows* specific and I haven't heard of any plans on making it cross-platform.

Comment: Microsoft Reference [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/ar-sa/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an impracticable question as there are too many to list.

However all .net standard functionality will be cross compatible to some degree

[.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

> The .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are
>   intended to be available on all .NET implementations. The motivation
>   behind the .NET Standard is establishing greater uniformity in the
>   .NET ecosystem. ECMA 335 continues to establish uniformity for .NET
>   implementation behavior, but there's no similar spec for the .NET Base
>   Class Libraries (BCL) for .NET library implementations.

[image]

**Additional Resources**

[API list in markdown](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/versions)

Also you might look at this

[.NET API analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer)

and

[The .NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, System namespaces should be available for use across platforms; they are part of .Net.  Windows would be platform specific.

I'd worry less about namespaces though and create a class library which targets NetStandard 2.0.  And then if you need to access some other library functionality, use Nuget to pull in the package you want.  Just make sure you're only pulling packages which target NetStandard themselves, and you should be fine, as NetStandard's goal is to define what all implementations of .Net must provide across platforms.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

If you do need to do UI libraries and controls, then you'll probably want to stick to Xamarin.Forms.  XF is meant to provide a common UI framework for iOS, Android, Mac, and Windows UWP.  Again, stick to the stock XF libraries and NetStandard 2.0, and you'll have the widest reach there.